# Unexpected "Uncaught TypeError: XXX is not a constructor" errors with Babel and ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I am giving a try to Webpack, and am giving a try to the instructions in [this tutorial](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/webpack-your-bags/), give or take a few custom things.

This is simple code, really, but I'm quite puzzled about this error, and feel this is something silly that I missed.

I defined two ES6 classes, each corresponding to a Handlebars template, and my app's entrypoint is supposed to replace the placeholder HTML in the index file by their contents:

**Entrypoint:**

```
import './bloj.less'

// If we have a link, render the Button component on it
if (document.querySelectorAll('a').length) {
    require.ensure([], () => {
        const Button = require('./Components/Button.js');
        const button = new Button('9gag.com');

        button.render('a');
    }, 'button');
}

// If we have a title, render the Header component on it
if (document.querySelectorAll('h1').length) {
    require.ensure([], () => {
        const Header = require('./Components/Header.js');

        new Header().render('h1');
    }, 'header');
}
```

**Index:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My title</h1>
    <a>Click me</a>

    <script src="build/bloj.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Button:**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import './Button.less';

export default class Button {

    constructor(link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    onClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(this.link);
    }

    render(node) {
        const text = $(node).text();
        var compiled = require('./Button.hbs');

        // Render our button
        $(node).html(
            compiled({"text": text, "link": this.link})
        );

        // Attach our listeners
        $('.button').click(this.onClick.bind(this));
    }
}
```

**Header:**

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import './Header.less';

export default class Header {
    render(node) {
        const text = $(node).text();
        var compiled = require('./Header.hbs');

        // Render the header
        $(node).html(
            compiled({"text": text})
        );
    }
}
```

Sadly, it does not work, and I get both these errors when displaying the page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Header is not a constructor
Uncaught TypeError: Button is not a constructor
```

**What could I be missing?**

Here is my webpack configuration:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
var appName = 'bloj';
var entryPoint = './src/bloj.js';
var outputDir =  './build/';
var publicDir = './build/';

// ************************************************************************** //

var plugins = [
    //new ExtractPlugin(appName + '.css', {allChunks: true}),
    new CleanPlugin(outputDir),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name:      'main',
        children:  true,
        minChunks: 2
    })
];

if (production) {
    plugins = plugins.concat([
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.MinChunkSizePlugin({
            minChunkSize: 51200 // 50ko
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            mangle:   true,
            compress: {
                warnings: false // Suppress uglification warnings
            }
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __SERVER__:      false,
            __DEVELOPMENT__: false,
            __DEVTOOLS__:    false,
            'process.env':   {
                BABEL_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        })
    ]);
}

module.exports = {
    entry:  entryPoint,
    output: {
        path:     outputDir,
        filename: appName + '.js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: publicDir
    },
    debug:   !production,
    devtool: production ? false : 'eval',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                loader: "babel",
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.less/,
                //loader: ExtractPlugin.extract('style', 'css!less')
                loader: "style!css!less"
            },
            {
                test:   /\.html/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.hbs/,
                loader: "handlebars-template-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: plugins,
    node: {
        fs: "empty" // Avoids Handlebars error messages
    }
};
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> What could I be missing?

Babel assigns default exports to the `default` property. So if you use `require` to import ES6 modules, you need to access the `default` property:

```
const Button = require('./Components/Button.js').default;
```

Comment: you can alternatively use `export var __useDefault = true;` and then you dont need the `.default`

Comment: @alfonsob using `var className = new ClassName.default()` currently works in the browser for me, where do I need to put that line in order to drop the `.default`?

Comment: @Brian, I got it, using ```export var __useDefault = true;```
You need to export your class as default: ```export default class MyClass```.
And you need to ```export var __useDefault = true;``` in the same file. I put just after

Comment: Given how hidden this pitfall is, and how much googling it took for me to find this solution, I'm shocked that this answer doesn't have even more upvotes than it does.

Comment: magic!, you are the best XD

Answer (score 11):

I realize that you already have an answer. However I had a similar issue to which I found an answer. Starting my own question and answering it seems weird.
So I'm just going to leave this here.

I had the same error as you got. However, I managed to solve it by changing my

```
export default {Class}
```

to

```
export default Class
```

I don't know why I wrapped the Class in an object but I remember having seen it somewhere so I just started using it.

So instead of the default returning a Class it returned an object like this `{Class: Class}`.
This is completely valid yet it will break webpack+babel.

EDIT: I've since come to know why this probably breaks babel+webpack. The `export default` is meant to only have 1 export. A javascript-object can contain many properties. Which means it can have more than 1 export. (See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export).

For multiple exports use: `export {definition1, definition2}`.

Use-case: I've used this in a situation where I've created a library which exported different types of an editor (while the underlying code was the same, the appearance of the editor changes depending on which export you use).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience of this error :)

Answer (score 7):

You can just put `export var __useDefault = true;` just after exporting your Class.

```
export default class Header {
...
} 
export var __useDefault = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by adding [`babel-plugin-add-module-exports`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-add-module-exports) to the `.babelrc` file

`npm install babel-plugin-add-module-exports --save-dev`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env"],
  "plugins": ["add-module-exports"]
}
```

this adds

```
module.exports = exports.default;
```

to the last line when compiling the class with babel.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the cause of your particular issue, I ran into a very similar problem when trying to rip babel out of an existing node app that was using ES6's `import` and `export` syntax, so this post is to help out anyone else struggling with this in the future.

Babel will resolve any circular dependencies between one module and another, so you can use ES6's `import` and `export` with reckless abandon. However, if you need to get rid of babel and use native node, you will need to replace any `import` and `exports` with `require`. This can reintroduce a latent circular reference issues that babel was taking care of in the background. If you find yourself in this situation, look for an area in your code that looks like this:

File A:

```
const B = require('B');

class A {
  constructor() {
    this.b = new B();
  }
}
module.exports = A;
```

File B:

```
const A = require('A'); // this line causes the error

class B {
  constructor() {
    this.a = new A();
  }
}
module.exports = B;
```

There are several different ways to resolve this issue depending on how you structured your code. The easiest way is probably to pass `B` a reference to `A` instead of creating a new instance of class `A`. You could also dynamically resolve the reference when loading `A`. There are a myriad of other alternatives, but this is a good place to get started.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the problem in this particular question, but for some reasons, babel does not hoist classes in the same file.

So if you declare your class `Token` at the top of the file, and write later `new Token()`, it will run.

If you declare your class after the constructor call, you will have the **xxx is not a constructor** error

Comment: Looks like not hoisting classes might just be a [javascript class thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_declarations), not a babel thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message and discovered that the cause was circular import statements.  That is:  I had two files that imported each other, wherein one file contained an `export default class` that contained a method that was dependent upon an `export function` from the other file.
My solution was to move one of the dependencies (functions) out of the class and into a `utils.js` file, which was a more appropriate place for it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I am using / importing my classes:

**Utils.class.js**

```
export default class Utils {
    somefunction(val) {
        return val
    }
}
```

**Using Utils into my controllers:**

```
import {default as U} from '../helpers/Utils.class';
const Utils = new U();

console.log(Utils.somefunction(123));
```